# In Ruby, why does "omega-3 (dHA)".gsub(/\b([a-z])/, '\0'.upcase) not work?

Tags: ruby, regex

I want to capitalize the first character of each word and leave the rest intact (so it is different from Rails's `titleize`, which downcase the rest).  The first line is a test, and third line works, but I wonder why the second line doesn't work?

```
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :026 > "omega-3 (dHA)".gsub(/\b([a-z])/, '#\0#')
 => "#o#mega-3 (#d#HA)" 

ruby-1.9.2-p180 :027 > "omega-3 (dHA)".gsub(/\b([a-z])/, '\0'.upcase)
 => "omega-3 (dHA)" 

ruby-1.9.2-p180 :028 > "omega-3 (dHA)".gsub(/\b([a-z])/) {|s| s.upcase}
 => "Omega-3 (DHA)"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`'\0'.upcase` calls the `upcase` method of the string `'\0'` - parens for invokation are optional in Ruby. Which of course does nothing, so the second line is just `.gsub(/.../, '\0')`

Comment: To expand a little, the second argument to the gsub method there is the expression `'\0'.upcase`. This is evaluated and the *result* of it is then passed to the gsub. Whereas in your third case, the gsub match is passed to the block, and *then* the `.upcase` method is called on the match.